# Roots and discrete logarithms

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to prove the following:

There are given numbers $p,a,b$, where $p$ is prime, $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a$, $p$ - coprime.
There also exist $r$ and $l$ such that $r^2 \equiv a\pmod p$ and $b^l \equiv a\pmod p$.
How can I prove, that there exists an $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $z^2 \equiv a\pmod p$ AND $b^z \equiv a\pmod p$?

I thought: if $r^2 \equiv a\pmod p$ and $b^l \equiv a\pmod p$ and $z^2 \equiv a\pmod p$ and $b^z \equiv a\pmod p$, then $r^2 = z^2 = b^l = b^z$, so $r = z = l = 2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is this correct? (I think this only holds true if I calculate in a certain Ring or Field, but I'm not sure.) The exercise points out at roots and discrete logarithms, but I don't know how to apply them here.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2):

The congruence $z^2\equiv a\pmod p$ holds whenever $z\equiv r\pmod p$.

Because $b^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ the congruence $b^z\equiv a\pmod p$ holds whenever $z\equiv \ell\pmod {p-1}$.

The Chinese Remainder Theorem is your friend, and gives you the claim.

Comment: In other words, there is no reason why you should find such a number $z$ *in the interval $[0,p)$*. You need to extend the search to $[0,p(p-1))$. Try it out for a few $p$, $a$, $r$, $b$!